# Neural Network Accuracy Drops to 0 after Some Epochs

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, lstm

I am training my Neural Network and the loss and accuracy graph look like this:
[image]

The training accuracy drops to 0 after epoch 55.
I am training Bi-LSTM for text classification. I use word embedding as the features and I use Adam as optimizer.

Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Comment: We would need additional info like what network and features and loss function and ....

Comment: Is this the validation accuracy or train accuracy?

Comment: I am training Bi-LSTM for text classification. I use word embedding as the features and I use Adam as optimizer.

Comment: This is training accuracy.

Comment: Provide your model's architecture and as well as some information regarding the data and the task which you are performing.